Is it possible to use Vertex AI exported AutoML Edge model(saved_model.pb stored in GCS ) file as pre-trained model for transfer learning
I trained an AutoML Edge model in Vertex AI using image dataset and I exported the trained model to GCS (saved_model.pb) and now i want to use this model as pre-trained model and train on new dataset and re-use it for transfer learning (by adding additional layers)
I tried to load it but it keeps throwing multiple errors like below

it was expecting .keras file format when tried to load it for tensorflow version 2.19.0
If i try to convert .pb file format to .keras and when i tried to load it it again throws one or the other Attribute Errors. so would like to know if it is possible to load AutoML edge model and use it as pre-trained model , Please let me know on this

code:
import tensorflow as tf

# Load the model from the .pb file
loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load('/home/jupyter/edge_model')

# Get the serving_default signature
infer = loaded_model.signatures['serving_default']

# Print the input tensor information
for input_tensor in infer.inputs:
    print(f"Input name: {input_tensor.name}")
    print(f"Input shape: {input_tensor.shape}")
    print(f"Input dtype: {input_tensor.dtype}")

output:
Input name: Placeholder:0
Input shape: (None,)
Input dtype: <dtype: 'string'>
Input name: Placeholder_1:0
Input shape: (None,)
Input dtype: <dtype: 'string'>

Code failure to load the AutoML Edge model:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load('/home/jupyter/edge_model')
# Load the pre-trained AutoML Edge model
base_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(loaded_model)

# Freeze the base model
base_model.trainable = False

# Add custom layers on top of the base model
model = models.Sequential([
    base_model,
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')  # num_classes should be the number of defect labels
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

